# Is there any way to restart the Diplomatic Immunity quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I’m doing diplomatic immunity and stupid me didn’t give the guy my gear so now I’m stuck with no gear and only magic. Just wondering if there is any way to restart the quest or go back to previous saves. This is on Xbox so pc methods won’t work.

Comment: Do you have a previous save? If you do have a previous, recent save, simply reload it. If not, you can simply lure out and kill one of the Thalmor Guards, and use his equipment. May not be as good what you are used to, but better than fist fighting or using only spells.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to restart this quest.

However, there are couple options available:

**1)** Load earlier save, then give the guy the appropriate gear (remember lockpicks!)

**2)** Sneak around in the mansion and get some gear.

**3)** Lower the game-difficulty and beat it.

You should have no unsolvable problems doing 2 and 3 together.